# git status: use absolute paths instead of relative

Tags: git, version-control

When I do `git status`, it shows files with relative paths:

```
modified:   foo
modified:   ../../etc/hosts
```

Relative paths are more unclear than absolute paths. I have to mentally retrace the path to see where the file is located.

How can I tell `git` to use absolute paths?

```
modified:   foo
modified:   /etc/hosts
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @LightBender, I have set `relativePaths = false` in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[status]
    howUntrackedFiles = all
    relativePaths = false
```

However, this has no effect. `git status` still shows relative paths as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [configuration section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_configuration) of the documentation for git-status:

You can set the configuration value `status.relativePaths` to false and git will display the paths relative to the project root (not the system root).

`git config [--global|local] status.relativePaths true`

As a side note, I tried this once and almost immediately got annoyed with having to constantly either type the magic signature for the project root (`:/`) at the start of every path or having to figure out which part I needed to use the path relatively in a command. Having git always present me with the path I need to use the file in a git command turned out to be preferable to me.

Comment: setting `relativePaths = false` in my `.gitconfig` does not have any effect. Please see my update.

Comment: `.gitconfig` or `~/.gitconfig`? Also check to see if any configs closer than the user config have the flag set, it's pretty easy to add it to the project config while you're working. `git config --list --show-origin` will list all config settings in order or precedence.

Comment: OK, so I was previously talking about `~/.gitconfig` and that did not work. Now I have added `relativePaths = false` to the actual `.git/config` file and it works. Bit instead of `/etc/foo` it uses `etc/foo` (without the slash at the beginning. Any way to use absolute paths starting with `/` ? Thank you.

Comment: @400theCat No, using absolute paths would require git to look outside the repository and as a rule it does not do that. This is actually a fairly odd request, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: what is so odd about wanting absolute paths (ie valid unix paths starting with `/`). Anything anything other seems odd to me. If `git status` show me etc/foo, I have to always prepend `/`, which is tedious.

Comment: @400theCat are you trying to version the entire volume?

Comment: not sure what you mean by entire volume. I do have `/` as git repository, and use git to version control my config files in `/etc`, `/home`, `/root`, ...

Comment: @400theCat Ahh, that explains a lot, it is very unusual to have a git repository positioned at the system root (`/`). (My instincts advise against it.) Git is designed to handle codebases, not volumes and it expects to have lots of them. Because git works from *its* root and that is not expected to be the system root, it makes sense that it would only show you files from its perspective (anything outside the project root doesn't exist to it). It is only because you're trying to use it to version a volume that this is even presenting as an issue. Short answer is no though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try

```
git status --porcelain
```